# Dynamic matrix inside struct, C programming

Tags: c, matrix, dynamic, struct

I need help. I want to learn how to create and use dynamic matrix which is element of structure, I want to fill matrix with zeros (0) and print it out, I tried many ways but no luck. Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct matrica
{
    int **mat;
    int dim; //this is dimension of squared matrix

}MATRICA;

void form_matrix(MATRICA *matrica);

int main()
{

    MATRICA matrix;

    form_matrix(&matrix);


    return 0;
}

void form_matrix(MATRICA *matrica)
{
    int i, j;
    MATRICA *br;

    do
    {
        printf("Size of matrix ");
        scanf("%d", &br->dim);

    }while(br->dim < 4 || br->dim > 6);

    matrica->mat = (int **) calloc(br->dim, sizeof(int *));

    for(i = 0; i < br->dim; i++)
    {
        matrica->mat[i] = (int *) calloc(br->dim, sizeof(int));

        for(j = 0; j < br->dim; j++)
        {
            matrica->mat[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < br->dim; i++)
        for(j = 0; j < br->dim; j++)
            printf("%d ", matrica->mat[i][j]);

}
```

what am I doing wrong, my loop inside function goes only once, can someone explain to me why?

Comment: which loop? you have mutiple loops.

Comment: first intended loop, when initialising matrix and filling with zeroes

Comment: What is the purpose of `br`, and why are you using it uninitialized?

Comment: `MATRICA *br;` --> `MATRICA *br = matrica;`

Comment: br is for accessing of dim inside of struct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program exhibits undefined behavior because you are dereferencing an uninitialized pointer `br`. You don't need it, you simply need a variable to store your dimension input.

```
int i, j, dim;

do
{
    printf("Size of matrix ");
    if (scanf("%d", &dim) != 1) {
        printf("scan failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

}while(dim < 4 || dim > 6);

matrica->dim = dim;
/* ... replace all instances of br->dim with dim */
```

Comment: Ok, I understand that, but I also want to use dim from struct, that is why I used br cause I want to use dim later in some other functions, so what I meant is that I need to store a number inside struct so I can use it again later inside some other function

Comment: Did you see `matrica->dim = dim;`?

Comment: ah, sorry, now I see what happened, thank you very much @jxh